# Loss of elements when switching orientations

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

i am building an application in which i have a `ScrollView` and inside of it i have a `LinearLayout` as child. Inside the layout i have other layouts and when i switch orientations i loose the first element which is an `EditText`.

The problemm is:

[image]

Landscape i loose the first element saying "Ονοματεπώνυμο"

[image]

and i slide up but it wont show.

My xml file code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context="com.project.matrix.lelemetroga.RegisterActivity">

    <include android:id="@+id/toolBar" layout="@layout/toolbar" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/fullname"
        android:id="@+id/registerUsername" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:id="@+id/registerPassword" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="@string/password_again"
            android:id="@+id/registerReapeatPassword" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Ημερομηνία Κατάταξης"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:id="@+id/dateKat" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Ημερομηνία Απόλυσης"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:singleLine="false" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="date"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:id="@+id/dateApol" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Όπλο/Σώμα"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/textView5" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                android:id="@+id/spinner3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/registerBtn" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I dont know why this happens but if anybody could point it out i would appreciate it!!!

Comment: Check if you have the same xml layout file name in folder layout-land?

Comment: i havent got a folder named layout-land because i design 1 layout for both orientations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have ordered the `LinearLayout` child to have its gravity

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

remove this line and make it like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Otherwise you will always wont be able to see the first edittext because it adjusts the screen to the center both vertical and horizontal!!!

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: glad to be able to help!!